# How does the resolve function in ELF files know what libs are the symbols in?

Tags: c++, debugging, elf

In the symbol table there is only the offset of symbol name but no information on which lib the symbol belongs to.

```
    typedef struct {
        Elf32_Word  st_name;
        Elf32_Addr  st_value;
        Elf32_Word  st_size;
        unsigned char   st_info;    /* bind, type: ELF_32_ST_... */
        unsigned char   st_other;
        Elf32_Half  st_shndx;   /* SHN_... */
    } Elf32_Sym;
```

When the resolving function is called at runtime, the offset of the symbol table and another DWORD are passed to it. Does that DWORD have something to do with the symbol's lib? If not then how does the resolving function find the lib of a symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does the resolving function find the lib of a symbol

By linear search of the libraries loaded into the the process (which the loader maintains).

The first library to define the given function "wins". This allows e.g. `libtcmalloc.so` to define `malloc`, `calloc`, etc. and to override these symbols (you either use `LD_PRELOAD`, or link `libtcmalloc` before `libc`, so `libtcmalloc` appears in the loader list before `libc` does).

The search is linear on the number of libraries, but is `O(1)` inside each library, because each library has a hash table of its symbols (in the `.hash` or `.gnu_hash` section).

Comment: Yes, ELF on constrast with Windows PE files and I think Apple Mac-O format do not tie an exported symbol to a given dynamic library: tjhey are searched in all library in breadth-first search (in the graph whose edges are the `DT_NEEDED` entries -- that is the dependencies bewteen ELF modules). The graph used is the global graph and not the subgraph of the current ELF file.