# Modify Binary Without Causing Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, binary, segmentation-fault, glibmm

I am new to patching binaries, but I would really like to get a package working on my system. I am trying to modify a binary package to fix an old link. The binary is trying to find the symbol `_ZN4Glib23spawn_command_line_syncERKSsPSsS2_Pi` however the `glibmm` library was changed and so trying to run this program fails with a symbol lookup error. Looking through the `glibmm` library I found what appears to be the new symbol `_ZN4Glib23spawn_command_line_syncERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEPS5_S8_Pi`. I tried then modifying the binary by replacing the old symbol string with the new one (using `vim` -- perhaps this is an issue); however, this causes a segmentation fault. I found that as long as I keep the symbol the same size then this does not occur.

How can I change this symbol in the binary without causing a segmentation fault?

I also have no idea if this will fix the problem or cause a whole bunch more problems so any more help is appreciated.

Comment: Even if you succeed in changing the name of the symbol it's exceedingly unlikely to actually work. Best bet is to just recompile the whole thing or find the older library (source if needed).  Also the symbol resolution is actually done using hashes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15193379/168175

Comment: @Flexo Recompiling is out of the question as I don't have the source. Looks like the only method is to downgrade the library...shucks